# Jquery (Datatables) features not fully initializing? php/mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I am attempting to apply Jquery's Datatables to display my database. In the example featured in this link, the table is searchable, can be ordered, and has nice color seperation.

http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

My current code displays the data, but with no sorting functionality, no search option, just the raw data, bold titles, and bars separating the rows (no alternating colors as in the example.) Pic with junk data: [image: css fail]

It seems it is applying some of the css but not all? I'm lost on why the functionality and remaining style is missing. I went back and put in html structure from my last code with the same results and no errors thrown.

Code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Sid, Fname, Lname, Email, Dtype, Mac, Date FROM StudentDeviceReg";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DataTables</title>
        <Meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


        <script src="media/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            @import "media/css/jquery.dataTables.css";
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#datatables').dataTable();
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <thead>

<?php

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table id='datatables' class='display'>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Device</th>
        <th>Mac Address</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>";
?>

            </thead>
            <tbody>

<?php


    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".$row["Sid"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Fname"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Lname"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Email"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Dtype"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Mac"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Date"]."</td>
          </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";


} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
            </tbody>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any errors thrown in console?

Comment: Negatory, no error log created

Comment: Are you sure your table is well structured? I would suggest you to check your page source code in the browser :-)  You print this:  `<thead> <table> </thead> <tbody> </table> </tbody>` (following your code)

Comment: I see what you're saying but I don't get how to fix that ordering considering the table is started in php brackets and must stop with echo </table>, whereas jquery needs th <t/heads> where they are to function I think?  Again I'm lost on how to fix that, I've never tried to get jquery and php/mysql listing.  I don't know why it would throw no errors and offer only some of the css like it's doing

Comment: @sylcat , take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table tree is not structured properly.

```
<body>
<div>

<?php

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   echo "
   <table id='datatables' class='display'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Device</th>
        <th>Mac Address</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "
      <tr>
        <td>".$row["Sid"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Fname"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Lname"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Email"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Dtype"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Mac"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Date"]."</td>
      </tr>";
    }
    echo "
    <tbody>
   </table>";
 }

?>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize you can nest tags inside php like that, still a bit new.  It's working now, thanks so much! :)